# Android error: Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Tags: java, android

I have the following code but cannot seem to figure out why I am getting the above error message. I obviously know what it means but I've checked the brackets and they seem correct to me. I'm running ADT 21.1.0. So far I've tried restarting Eclipse; restarting my PC; and re-building the project.

```
package cct.mad.lab;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WalkList extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] players = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.players);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, players));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick (ListView 1, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: at which line you getting this error

Comment: Are you really trying to call that ListView parameter "1"? I'd think that might be confusing the compiler somewhat.

Comment: ListView 1, eclipse is surely warning you about that

Comment: `1` is no valid variable name.

Comment: Yes it actually is, although that's a separate issue altogether. Vino I am getting the error on the last bracket.

Comment: @Ciaran No, seriously, it's not. And I think it's probably what's confusing the compiler. Really, change the name from "1" to "lv" or something temporarily and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @MattGibson I didn't relate that to the error message; but it did fix it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly because of an invalid identifier defined in the `onListItemClick` definition.

Change the `ListView` identifier in `onListItemClick` from `1` to something else (a valid identifier).

From [jls-3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, **the first of which must be a Java letter**.

More about the Java letter:

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   `A-Z (\u0041-\u005a)`, and `a-z (\u0061-\u007a)`, and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore `(_, or \u005f)` and dollar sign (`$`, or
>   `\u0024`). The `$` character should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is being confused by the use of "1" as an identifier. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645273/why-can-an-identifier-not-start-with-a-number) hopefully gives some insight as to why variable names in Java can't start with a number, but fundamentally, it's in the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).