# How to map Json to Java classes when some variable names begin with a number?

Tags: java, json, deserialization

Recently I've been playing with a webservice that returns a `json` object like this

```
{
  "id": 88319,
  "dt": 1345284000,
  "name": "Benghazi",
  "coord": {
    "lat": 32.12,
    "lon": 20.07
  },
  "main": {
    "temp": 306.15,
    "pressure": 1013,
    "humidity": 44
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1,
    "deg": -7
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 90
  },
  "rain": {
    "3h": 3
  }
}
```

I have automatically generated Java classes mapping to that json data. The problem is I cannot generate a Java class with an attribute named **3h** (in Java as in many other languages variable identifiers cannot begin with a number). As a hack around I have redefined the attribute **3h** as **h3**, and whenever I receive a json response from the web service I replace the string "3h" by "h3".

However, that approach is only appropriate for small projects. I would like to know if there is a more convenient approach to deal with this kind of situation.

Notes: For this particular example I used an online tool that generated the java classes given a json example. In other situations I have used Jackson, and other frameworks. ¿Is the answer to this question framework dependent? To be more concrete, and having the future in mind, I would like to adhere to the json-schema specification

Comment: Why are you making attributes into classes?

Comment: how is the binding done? which framework are you using?

Comment: The best solution would likely depend on the JSON marshaller you chose to use. Gson? Jackson? other?

Comment: @JB Nizet I came into this problem while using Gson, but I also use Jackson in other projects, so a more general answer (not limited to a single library) would be highly valuable.

Comment: @gurvinder372 For this particular example I used an online tool that generated the java classes given a json example. In other situations I have used Jackson, and other frameworks. ¿Is the answer to this question framework dependent? To be more concrete, and having the future in mind, I would like to adhere to the [json-schema](http://json-schema.org) specification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you can do it with `@SerializedName` annotation.

*Java Class:*

```
public class JsonData {

    @SerializedName("3h")
    private int h3;

    private String name;

    public JsonData(int h3, String name) {
        this.h3 = h3;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

*Serialization: (same class works for **fromJson()** as well)*

```
// prints: {"3h": 3,"name": "Benghazi"}
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(new JsonData(3, "Benghazi")));
```

***Reference:***
[*@SerializedName* Annotation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: I have tried that and it works. I guess this tag may be valid for some libraries but not for others, or is it something pretty standard? In the past I remember working with XML files, using the JAXB compiler to automatically generate Java classes, and those tags where automatically generated, so I guess some tools to generate code do this, while others do not.

Comment: @magomar Yes, you're correct. While *Gson* uses *@SerializedName*, a quick Google search found *Jackson* using [@JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) for the same. So, the annotations (just like the API) are not standard but mostly the libraries do provide such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you're looking for. Simple as it seems, getting the syntax right took me a while.

```
public class Rain {
    @JsonProperty("3h")
    public BigDecimal detail = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
}
```

You may not need it, but I set the default to 0.
"3h" is the name of the key.
"detail" is the name I gave the property to hold the value that WAS represented by "3h".

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the data type of the property you are generating. Like arr_,int_,obj_ etc for respective objects because during autogeneration, you will anyway have to deal with the datatype. This will become a general fix rather than specifically looking for strings like "3h". But design-wise or good-practice wise this might not be the most optimal solution.

Comment: I am accessing a web service, so I get the data as it is, I cannot change the json keys. Also see my comment to rahulserver above...

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to know if there is a more convenient approach to deal with this kind of situation."

Firstly I can not make out what "this kind of situation" is since you have not mentioned the frameworks or approach by which you are making the mapping.

And if you want to have the attribute identifiers mapping to your json keys, to begin with numbers, it is not possible and that too is for good only.

Since,say for example if your last subdocument:

```
"rain": {
    "3h": 3
  }
```

is mapped to a class Rain as:

```
class Rain{
   int 3h=3
}
```

Then how will you parse the variable assignment "3h=3" ?(Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1645335/1291122) SO post)

So what I can think of a way is that maybe you can prefix any keys starting with numbers with special legal identifier charatcers (like "_" underscore) and later on remove the assignment.

Which means, you can map your json subdocument rain as:

```
class Rain{
   int _3h=3
}
```

And later remove the leading underscore while deserializing.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Sounds like my answer below :).. But no issues

Comment: @rahulserver  Thanks, but I am trying to avoid any "hacking", I would like to use standard solutions like the use of tags for this purpose, as suggested in the selected answer. Furtheremo, I know some code generators will automatically add these tags when appropriate, so IMHO that is the way to go.